# Is it a good pratice to implement Array methods on Object.prototype for NodeList objects?

Tags: javascript, dom

For executing array methods on NodeList objects(Array like) we need to make indirect call on Array.prototype every time.

Can we do something so that `node_list.slice(0,1)` is possible?

As NodeList inherits methods from Object.prototype, i implemented like below and works 
perfectly `node_list.slice(0,1)`

```
Object.prototype.slice = function(a,b){ return Array.prototype.slice.call(this,a,b);}
```

Is there any disadvantage on implementing slice on Object.prototype?

Legacy way to call on Array.prototype:

```
node_list
[<li>​ test_list1 ​</li>​, <li>​ test_list2 ​</li>​]

Object.prototype.toString.call(node_list)
"[object NodeList]"

var content = Array.prototype.slice.call(node_list,0,1)

content
[<li>​ test_list1 ​</li>​]

Object.prototype.toString.call(content)
"[object Array]"
```

Comment: When people write code like this, I weep inside

Comment: Why don't you use a `toArray` function like everyone else does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to extend the Object's prototype for this reason.
Even if you want to extend a built-in prototype, reduce the extension to the necessary parts:

```
HTMLCollection
NodeList
```

Prototype methods which don't show up in a `for(.. in ..)` loop can be defined as follows:

```
var slicer = { value: Array.prototype.slice };
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCollection.prototype, 'slice', slicer);
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'slice', slicer);
```

See also:

- [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

### Shortest way (without extending prototypes)

```
// Equivalent to the question's code
[].slice.apply(node_list,0,1)
// A method to turn a node_list/HTMLCollection in an array (for later use?)
[].slice.call(node_list);
```

Comment: what API returns a HTMLCollection ?

Comment: @Raynos [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) for example

Comment: Then again we have to define NodeList.prototype.array_method and HTMLCollection.prototype.array_method

Comment: @Praveen Can you live with the updated method? Simply replace `Array.prototype` with `[]` (a new instance is created, but for quick debugging purposes, it's not harmful).

Comment: one last question, NodeList.prototype.slice = Array.prototype.slice works fine [ node_list.slice(0,2) works ]but Object.prototype.slice = Array.prototype.slice doesn't work and i get error node_list.slice(0,2) => TypeError: Property 'slice' of object #<NodeList> is not a function

Comment: @Praveen In which browser are you seeing this? It does not happen in Chrome 18 and FF 11: http://jsfiddle.net/3kgVR/

Comment: hey i was doing some mistake extension of Object as well as NodeList both works. thanks..

Comment: Bear in mind that in IE < 9, the constructors and prototypes of `NodeList` (and other host objects and collections) are not accessible from JavaScript, and furthermore do not inherit from `Object.prototype`, so it is not possible to extend them.